# Loading fonts dynamically. Javascript: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, nginx, cors

I'm trying to load fonts dynamically using this function.

```
...
    // Load Font
    function loadFont(url, fontName) {
        if (!isFontAvailable(fontName)) {
            let fontObject = new FontFace(fontName, 'url(' + url + ')');
            fontObject.withCredentials = true;
            fontObject.load().then(function (loaded_face) {
                document.fonts.add(loaded_face);
                document.body.style.fontFamily = fontName + ', Arial';
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("loadFont: " + error);
            });
        }
    }
```

But I get these following errors:

```
Access to font at 'http://localhost/fonts/iransans/IRANSansLight.ttf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
IRANSansLight.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I'm using Nginx as my web server. I added this block of code to my configuration file.

```
location ~* "^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$" {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers true;
}
```

I checked my response headers too:

```
/var/www$ curl -I http://localhost/fonts/iransans/IRANSansLight.ttf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 16:50:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 59968
Last-Modified: Sun, 03 Mar 2019 20:30:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c7c3979-ea40"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: true
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

As you can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is right there. But I don't know why error says: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present".

By the way, I tried other methods to load my fonts like this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/zejz2tkp/1/
But didn't work either, I mean nothing changed. Of course, I edited that JsFiddle a little and it's another story.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache? I'd expect the font (including the lack of CORS permissions) to be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to clear the browser cache. Thanks to @Quentin it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

> Access to font at 'http://localhost/fonts/iransans/IRANSansLight.ttf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The "origin `null`" in there means the page loading the font is not being loaded from an HTTP URL (e.g., `http://` or `https://`). Usually this means you've loaded the page from a `file://` URL by double-clicking it in a file explorer or similar. Some browsers (such as Chrome) refuse to allow pages with origin `null` to access anything cross-origin, headers or no headers. Origin `null` doesn't match anything, not even `*` (by their reasoning).

Instead, don't load the page from a `file://` URL. Use an `http://` or `https://` URL (perhaps one accessing a locally-running web server).